# Is a variable declaration inside a loop static declaration or dynamic?

Tags: programming, loop

```
while(condition){ 
    Object object = new Object();
}
```

So my question is, will each iteration would create a different object in different memory location or it will overwrite the once created object every iteration.

Comment: You are strongly encouraged not to use dynamic memory allocations. Due to the low ammount of memory you will get into trouble if you are not careful. Try to avoid calls like new and malloc. instead you should use `Object object(args);` to initialize your object in the loop. It will be disposed at the end of the loop automatically.

Comment: This code is not proper C/C++, it should be `Object* object = new Object();` otherwise this would not even compile.

Answer (score 2):

It will be created every iteration.

Assuming, you are not using it to add to a list (e.g. to use in later loops), what you better can do is make it in a global, you also don't need to use 'new', thus:

```
Object object;
```

Also, if you do not delete/remove the object at the end of each while condition (with the *delete* keyword), you will lose the memory (and this is a memory leak). Also, you run the risk of memory shortage (the Uno has only a few KB of memory).

What I also miss in your code is the pointer (*, because the *new* keyword creates a pointer), and also Obj and Object are inconsistent types (they should be equal), so:

```
Object* object = new Object();
```

If you only need the object within the condition and it can be removed in the next while, than you don't need to use new, so just declare it as a vaiable

```
Object object;
```

This also has the benefit that the (local) variable will be destroyed at the end of scope (which is at the end of the while).

Comment: maybe also mention cleaning up the object when using `new`

Comment: @ratchetfreak I already put a notice for that, but I extended the comment slightly.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean memory *leak* instead of memory *breach*? First time I hear "memory breach", google does not seem to know what a memory breach is neither.

Comment: @wondrea memory leak is indeed a better word, I change it

Answer (score 1):

**Dynamic** object creation is using operator `new`. Operator `new` creates object on *heap* and the object exits until you delete it with operator `delete`.

`Object object` creates object on *stack*. It will be removed from stack when the variable goes out of scope on the end of the block.

**Some classes have copy constructors. If your `Object object = new Object()` compiles, then the class Object has copy constructor. The code creates an object on stack, then creates an object on heap and then copies it's content into object on stack. The object on heap stays and you have no pointer to it to delete it. The program soon crashes on low memory.**

**Static** variables have keyword static. If you would have `static Object* object = new Object()`, then the pointer is created on global level and the object on heap is created and assigned only ones.

EDIT:
I tested this. Class String has a copy constructor, but the Arduino compiler doesn't allow `String s = new String(a)`. It can be misleaded with `String s = *(new String(a))` (`a` is some variable).

Comment: reason for the down-vote?